# How to draw a single point using Turtle Graphic

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there any way to draw a single point using Turtle library instead of drawing a square? I would love to use less memory and be able to draw it faster. At the moment I am using this:

```
    def draw_p(alex, d):
    # trick to save local state PUSH
        cwd = alex.position() 
        alex.pendown()
        alex.forward(d)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(d)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(d)
        alex.left(90)
        alex.forward(d)
        alex.penup()
        alex.goto(cwd) # POP retrieve back to enter state
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the method `penup()` instead of `pendown()` if you don't want to draw while the cursor is moving, then you'll draw only points.

Besides, you could change the arrow-style shape for a circle-style shape.

I've written a simple code to create a spiral made up of several points.

### Code (Updated)

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(800, 600)
wn = turtle.Screen()

spiral = turtle.Turtle()
spiral.color("blue")
spiral.penup()      
          
size = 10
for i in range(35):
  spiral.dot()                
  size = size + 2             
  spiral.forward(size)          
  spiral.right(24)
```

### Plot

[image]

Comment: Thanks Manel! Could I use turtle.dot instead of turtle.stamp?

Comment: @Quelms, I'm glad i helped. Answering your question, Sure, why not?, you are right . I've already updated the code. Thank you :D